# What is the correct approach to refresh a running production environment

Tags: bash, shell-script, environment-variables

I am not showing much code here , but I have a requirement to fix.
We have file with over 100 function that are being used in various shell scripts in production.
We have named it as.

```
functions.sh
```

Up-till now each script call this "functions.sh" file in it so it can access the updated function. Like this

```
#!/bin/bash
# comment
# comment
# Comment

./path/function.sh

echo "Date" > logging()
..
```

Now we have been asked to get rid of this call :

```
./path/function.sh
```

from scripts that will be developed in future.
(so that more such files can be added) & make sure latest functions are  automatically refreshed in environment as soon as new "functions.sh" is deployed to production and any scripts can use the function defined in them directly .
Shall I just call it in .bashrc file as

```
~/.functions.sh
```

or is there anything else we have to do , keeping in mind scripts will be executed in non-interactive mode through crontab. ( all scripts are bash scripts )
any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: A title like "best way" trends dangerously towards asking for opinions. Can you find another way to phrase it?

Comment: @jeff any suggestion from your experience

Comment: I can't make out what your question/problem is, yet.

Comment: @JeffSchaller Updated Question , what Can I do to make it clear. I am in a real situation here.

Comment: Your point about being run via cron isn't a minor thing, that kind of changes everything. Please [edit] your question and tell us _exactly_ how you will run these scripts that need the functions and also how you define the functions and if they are exported. Also, how do you load the functions? Did you really mean you run `~/.functions.sh` or did you actually mean `. ~/.functions.sh`? We would also need to know your OS since some details may change.

Comment: Replacing "best way" with "correct approach" doesn't help much as it is not clear what "correct" means in your environment. To me it is not clear what you mean with "get rid of this call from scripts for future application **(so that more such files can be added)**". If you want to add more files to define functions, you could source these files from `functions.sh`. Please describe in more detail what is the problem with calliing `. functions.sh`?

Comment: @Bodo I have update the question and added more information. We don't have to use the call to functions.sh at all, script have to use the function from environment itself.

Answer (score 0):

Read https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Startup-Files

For non-interactive shells (such as running a script via cron), bash uses the `BASH_ENV` environment variable as the name of a file to source.

So, for maximum flexibility, you can do something like this:

```
/some/path
├── functions.d
│   ├── func1.sh
│   ├── func2.sh
│   ├── ...
│   └── funcN.sh
└── functions.sh
```

And `functions.sh` could be

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
func_dir="${BASH_SOURCE[0]%/*}/functions.d"
if [[ -d "$func_dir" ]]; then
    for f in "$func_dir"/*.sh; do
        if [[ -r "$f" ]]; then
            . "$f"
        fi
    done
fi
```

In your crontab file, add

```bsh
BASH_ENV=/some/path/functions.sh
```

So all you have to do is add a .sh file to that directory, and your cron scripts will source it.

This gives you the flexibility to create files each containing just a single function definition. No more giant library files.

Comment: thanks < I will try and update it here.